# Convert the height value in percents to the width value in percents in svg using d3.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, svg

How could I convert the height value in percents to the width value in percents in `svg` using `d3.js`?

I need this in order to get a square shaped `svg` element on the tip of a rectangle, such a square that its side`s length is equal to the rectangle`s height. And this I need because I want to draw a pencil icon in that `svg` just like that:

[image]

Having a separate `svg` element for drawing the pencil will allow me to make the pencil responsive by manipulationg the `viewBox` attribute values (while the pencil icon will be drawn using the `path` element).

So, the problem I am facing is that the percents of the height represent a different measurement in the width. For example, `10%` in height have a different meaning from `10%` in width (in other words if width is 100 and height is 10, then `10%` in height is one and `10%` in width is 10).

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/76uedo40/195/) is a fiddle.

```js
debugger;
const svg = d3.select("#drawRegion")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", "100%")
  .attr("height", "100%");
svg.append("rect")
  .attr("x", "0")
  .attr("y", "0")
  .attr("width", "100%")
  .attr("height", "100%")
  .attr("fill", "yellow");
  
const innerRectX = 10;
const innerRectY = 10;
const innerRectWidth = 80;
const innerRectHeight = 30;
const innerRect = svg
.append("rect");
innerRect
.attr("x", innerRectX + "%")
.attr("y", innerRectY + "%")
.attr("width", innerRectWidth + "%")
.attr("height", innerRectHeight + "%")
.attr("fill", "pink");

const squareSideLength = innerRectHeight;
const squareX = innerRectX + innerRectWidth - squareSideLength;
const squareY = innerRectY;
const mustBecomeASquare = svg
.append("svg");
mustBecomeASquare
.attr("x", squareX + "%")
.attr("y", squareY + "%")
.attr("width", squareSideLength + "%")
.attr("height", squareSideLength + "%")
.append("rect")
.attr("x", 0)
.attr("y", 0)
.attr("width", "100%")
.attr("height", "100%")
.attr("fill", "green");
```

```html
<div id="drawRegion">

</div>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

As you can see the green `rect` is not a square.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get width and height of `#drawRegion` using d3. Use those values to draw `rect` of same width and height.

```
const width = parseInt(d3.select("#drawRegion").style("width"));
const height = 150;

const svg = d3.select("#drawRegion")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

svg.append("rect")
    .attr("x", "0")
    .attr("y", "0")
    .attr("width", "100%")
    .attr("height", "100%")
    .attr("fill", "yellow");

const innerRectHeight = 0.3 * height;
const innerRectWidth = width - ((0.2 * width) + innerRectHeight);
svg.append("rect")
    .attr("x", "10%")
    .attr("y", "10%")
    .attr("width", innerRectWidth)
    .attr("height", innerRectHeight)
    .attr("fill", "pink");

const greenRectPos = innerRectWidth + (0.1 * width);
svg.append("rect")
    .attr("x", greenRectPos)
    .attr("y", "10%")
    .attr("width", innerRectHeight)
    .attr("height", innerRectHeight)
    .attr("fill", "green");
```